# Unable to connect to API in my Heroku/Express app

Tags: express, heroku

I have an Express app deployed on Heroku, and the AJAX calls that worked successfully locally no longer work on the deployed app.

For example, when the AJAX call's url was http://localhost:3001/api/trusts, the call returned successfully.

However, when the AJAX call's url in the deployed app is https://someapp.herokuapp.com/api/trusts, it gives me a 404 error.

How do I correct my url on the AJAX call? I'm at my wit's end.

Here is my server.js:

```
 //server.js
'use strict'

//first we import our dependencies...
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import sitesRoutes from './src/routes/sitesRoutes';
import trustsRoutes from './src/routes/trustsRoutes';

//and create our instances
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

//set our port to either a predetermined port number if you have set it up, or 3001
var port = process.env.API_PORT || 3001;

//db config
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://SOMEUSERNAME:SOMEPASSWORD!@XXX.mlab.com:XXX/XXX';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

//now we should configure the API to use bodyParser and look for JSON data in the request body
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//To prevent errors from Cross Origin Resource Sharing, we will set our headers to allow CORS with middleware like so:
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');


  //and remove cacheing so we get the most recent comments
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  next();
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      app.get(/^\/(?!api).*/, (req, res) => { // don't serve react app to api routes
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
      });
};

app.use('/api', router);

sitesRoutes(router);
trustsRoutes(router);

//starts the server and listens for requests
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`api running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your port number.  According to the docs, you should use the port number Heroku provisions for you, which is in the `PORT` environment variable.

So perhaps try changing:

`var port = process.env.API_PORT || 3001;`

to

`var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;`

Comment: Thanks, Jon. The problem is that I can only get it to work correctly in the AJAX call is if I hardcode the url (i.e., "http://localhost:3100/api/trusts". Otherwise, it returns a 404. The problem seems to be it's using the base URL on relative paths as the main port and not the designated API port. Does that make sense?